# jquery datepicker apply css to a subsequent class

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

I have more than one jquery datepicker instances in a page. For one instance, I need to show only the year. I don't want to show month. After digging a bit, I found that the month can be hidden by

```
.ui-datepicker-month {
    display:none;
}
```

But, on doing this, the month is hidden in other datepicker instances as well.
So, here is what I tried next.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonText: 'Show Date',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonImage: "calendaricon.png",
        changeMonth: false,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: false,
        dateFormat: 'yy',

        beforeShow: function() {

            $(".ui-datepicker-month").css("display", "none");
        },
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 

            var month = 0;
            var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            $(".ui-datepicker-month").css("display", "inline");
        }
    });
});
```

The css of .ui-datepicker-month does not change at all. How can I hide the month completely? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add focus event:-

```
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
  changeMonth: false,
  changeYear: false,
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  duration: 'fast'
})
.focus(function() {
    $(".ui-datepicker-month").remove();
});
```